# Ruby on Rails Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering how can I reach my data in the following situation

I have a resource called Pages, it has all actions possible and was created has Ryan bate proposed on his railscast at http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages?autoplay=true. Now I have used the layout folder has follow

application.html.erb

```
_footer.html.erb
_header.html.erb
```

The page have a permalink and I want them to be in the _footer section so it could be About Us, Term and Condition, etc...

So here what I have done
application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>
```

Which calls _footer in the layouts folder
This is _footer.html.erb

```
<footer class="footer">
<small>
Copyright <%= Time.now.year %>
</small>
<nav><%= render "pages/link" %>
<ol class="footer_pages"> 
</ol>
</nav>
</footer>
```

which call a file in the Pages/_link.html.erb
This is the file

```
<li>
<%= @pages.each do |page| %>
<%= page.name %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

At this points pages.each isn't initialize and doesn't work if i am correct So what i did his initialize @pages = Page.all in the controller applicationController because its the caller. This theory should allow me to read it, but it still doesn't work! What i am doing wrong?

Update since i don't know how to add other comments
applicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
@pages = Page.all
end
```

Comment: First thing that jumps out at me is you are trying to render output from @pages.each, which you shouldn't. Use `<% %>` for that line instead of `<%= %>`. Otherwise, what error are you actually seeing?

Comment: Thanks didn't see it, NoMethodError, undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, the line code is <% @pages.each do |page| %> in the _link.html.erb

Comment: Show the relevant code from your `ApplicationController`

Comment: Typical applicationController from tutorialorg  
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use an before_filter in the ApplicationController that will set the @pages instance variable.  Then all pages will have access to this data.

Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :pages

  def pages
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you render the partial, the variables from your controller are not passed to the partial. In other words, the partial has never heard of `@pages` even though you initialized it in the controller.

Try passing the variables `@pages` to the partial like this:

```
# page the partial is first called from
<%= render 'layouts/footer', :locals => {:pages => @pages} %>

# _footer.html.erb
<%= render "pages/link", :locals => {:pages => pages} %>

# _link.html.erb
<li>
<%= pages.each do |page| %>
<%= page.name %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

See [http://guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more information. (Rendering partials is about 80% down the page)